# Deserialize Json arrays and simple object

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

I´m deserializing a JSON response and there is a object that could be an array or a simple object, for example:

```
{  
   "ValueAdds":{  
      "@size":3,
      "ValueAdd":[  
         {  
            "description":"desc 1"
         },
         {  
            "description":"desc 1"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and the other case:

```
{
  "ValueAdds": {
    "@size": "1",
    "ValueAdd": {
      "description": "Internet inalámbrico gratuito"
    }
  }
}
```

The entities:

```
public ValueAddsWrap 
{
     public ValueAddBase ValueAdds { set; get; }
}

public class ValueAddBase
{
    public ValueAdd[] ValueAdd { set; get; }
}

public class ValueAdd
{
    public string description { set; get; }
}
```

I´m getting an exception when I receive a simple object. How could I design the entities in order to deserialize an array and a simple object?

I´m using Newtonsoft:

```
T resp_object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

and the exception:

```
    An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'rce.bookings.business.expedia.Responses.ValueAdd[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: To see some code of what you tried so far will be necessary. Additionally, You can only fill Object with the given Data and not do actions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a JsonConverter:

```
public class ValueAddsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var valueAdds = new ValueAdds();
        var jo = (JObject)JObject.Load(reader)["ValueAdds"];

        valueAdds.Size = Int32.Parse((string)jo["@size"]);

        if (valueAdds.Size > 1)
        {
            valueAdds.ValueAdd = jo["ValueAdd"].Children().Select(x => x.ToObject<ValueAdd>());
        }
        else
        {
            valueAdds.ValueAdd = new List<ValueAdd>{jo["ValueAdd"].ToObject<ValueAdd>()};
        }

        return valueAdds;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof (ValueAdds));
    }
}

public class ValueAdd
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof (ValueAddsConverter))]
public class ValueAdds
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValueAdd> ValueAdd { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You really can't do what I think you're asking. In the first case you've got a collection inside the object you're getting back.

```
public class ValueAdd
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ValueAdds
{
    public int size { get; set; }
    public List<ValueAdd> ValueAdd { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ValueAdds ValueAdds { get; set; }
}
```

In the second case you've got a single instance of an object.

```
public class ValueAdd
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ValueAdds
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public ValueAdd ValueAdd { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ValueAdds ValueAdds { get; set; }
}
```

You might be able to get away with using a `dynamic` for the `ValueAdd` member, but that presents a whole bunch of annoying problems of its own as you'll still have to figure out whether it contains a collection or a single instance.

Realistically I see you have two options:

Option #1: Figure out if you've got the version with the collection or the single instance and deserialize into the appropriate type.

Option #2: Can you contact the author of the API and have them send back a consistent JSON structure? That's a lousy API if it changes the structure based on whether there are one or more than one ValueAdd objects.

Comment: I´m receiving only one json response that include the both cases and I'm deserializing the complete json using newtonsoft.The Option 2 is not possible. How could I implement the option 1 using JsonConvert? Is there some rules in the JsonConvert definition?